# Catch remote notification while application is in Background

Tags: iphone, background, push-notification, ios4

Is there a way to catch remote push notification while the application is "running" in Background ?

I have implemented the delegate function didReceiveRemoteNotification, and would like it to catch the remote notification while the application is in Background in the new iPhone OS 4.0

The application is correctly in background, since it keep the old state it was when I press the home button. But the push notification is appearing has a popup just like it should when the application is not running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just can't... :-( Too bad Apple's hasn't think about this...

Comment: File a bug if you want this feature.